# How to contribute a context menu to a custom view in an eclipse plug-in project?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, view, eclipse-plugin, popup

In an eclipse plug-in project, I contributed a view named `Favorites` with id `com.qualityeclipse.favorites.views.FavoritesView`.

Then I want to contribute a context menu to the `Favorites` view by using `popup:com.qualityeclipse.favorites.views.FavoritesView?after=additions`.
However, no context menu shows up upon a right-click within the `Favorites` view.

I changed it to `popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions` for test. This time a context menu appears as expected in other views (such as `Problems`, `Console`, and `Declaration`) than my own `Favorites` view.

> How to contribute a context menu to a custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a context menu in your view code and register it with the view site. Something like:

```java
ISelectionProvider provider = ... a selection provider such as a TreeViewer or TableViewer

Control control = control to own the menu - usually the TreeViewer or TableViewer control

MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopUp");
menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);

menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
       // Additions placeholder
       manager.add(new Separator(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));

       // Note: you can add other menu items directly here
    }
});

Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(control);
control.setMenu(menu);

// register the context menu such that other plug-ins may contribute to it
getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, provider);
```

Comment: Thanks. Could this be done declaratively instead of programmatically? The code here seems rather routine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions
```

But then, add some conditions to each command (with `right click > New > Visible When` :

This one make it visible when the active part is your view

```
     <visibleWhen
        checkEnabled="false">
     <with
           variable="activePartId">
        <equals
              value="com.qualityeclipse.favorites.views.FavoritesView">
        </equals>
     </with>
  </visibleWhen>
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem directly. The answer of @greg-449 makes the context menu *show up* upon a right-click within my own view. And your answer can be used to restrict the "any" context menu to my own view. Thanks.